# Evaluating If Statements in Liquid Template Not Producing Boolean

Tags: liquid

I am using Liquid templates, which are available for customizing desk.com templates.

While iterating over a collection in a for loop, I'm trying to catch the index halfway through the collection and split into another column.

Here's my code snip:

```
{% capture half_topics %}{{ topics_count | divided_by:2 }}{% endcapture %}
<div>TEST Topics Count: {{ topics_count }}</div>
<div>TEST Half: {{ half_topics }}</div>

<div class="bt-column">
  {% for topic in topics %}
    <div>TEST Forloop Index: {{ forloop.index }}</div>
    <div>TEST Are we there yet?: {{ this_index }}</div>
    {% if forloop.index == half_topics %}
      <div>TEST This is where a column split should go</div>
      </div><div class="bt-column">
    {% endif %}
    <h4>{{ topic.name }}</h4>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

And here's a chunk of the output:

```
TEST Topics Count: 7
TEST Half: 3

TEST Forloop: 1
TEST Are we there yet?: 1
Topic 1

TEST Forloop: 2
TEST Are we there yet?: 2
Topic 2

TEST Forloop: 3
TEST Are we there yet?: 3
Topic 3

TEST Forloop: 4
TEST Are we there yet?: 4
Topic 4
```

Note that the output for (what I think) should be boolean is instead the same integer as the forloop.index. I don't know if that comparison expression even works in an output value like that, but in any case you can see that it's not evaluating to the right boolean, as far as I can tell. You can also see that the column break never happens.

The Googles apparently have nothing to say about this, OR I'm lousy at the Googles. :)